# Run the same python file multiple times with different input values

Tags: python

I have a process that will take input and then run the in background and evaluate infomation (assuming the process never ends) which means the file basically "stops" I am not able to motify any of the variables. My process has "stages" and these "stages" require the same evaluation but different input and since I am not able to motify the variables, I am left with making another python file and then changing the variables, and then running that. My process has to be ran by file, and cannot be defined as a function or loop.

**test1.py**

```py
from .test import testing #-- my manager to calculate the variable data returns a list

value = 473
drones = testing(473) #- returns something like [[0,1,2,3], [4,5,6,7]]
while True: #- The loop in a nutshell, but cannot be defined as a loop or function
  process(drones[0]) #- process is the process in a nutshell
```

- Note: Line 1 `from .test import testing` is a manager I have made to divide input to data for my process.
- Note: Line 4 `drones = testing(473)` returns a list of lists; each value in the list is the necessary data for one process.
- Note: Line 5 `while True:` this is my loop in a nutshell this is not how it is actually handled*

**test2.py**

```py
from .test import testing 

value = 473
drones = testing(473) 
while True: 
  process(drones[1])
```

This is different from test1.py in line 6 `process(drones[1])`. The data I'm using for my process is different in test1.py (`process(drones[0])`)

But what if I have hundreds, maybe thousands? I wouldn't just make individual files for that.

I am open to all answers. These answer do not have to be purely python (bash, etc.).

Comment: you can use `sys.argv` to start the same file with different arguments.

Comment: sadly, it's not possible

Answer (score 0):

you could use [`multiprocessing.Pool`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool):

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool

from .test import testing

value = 473
drones = testing(value)

def proc(lst):
    # do something with lst asynchonously

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pool = Pool(2) # or however many times needed
    pool.map(proc, drones, chunksize=1) # runs proc(drones[0]), proc(drones[1]), ..., each in their own process
```

Comment: Im a bit confused `pool.map(proc, drones)`, this only runs `drones` but I want this to run for each value in drones, it is possible to put a loop in `if __name__ == "__main__":`?

Comment: The first parameter to `pool.map()` is a function that is called on each part of the iterable. It's basically the built-in `map()` function, but calls the function in it's own process.

Comment: So you are saying it iterates through the list by itself??

Comment: Yes. [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.map)

Comment: Hm, the only problem with this, is that my "process" isn't actually a function nor a loop, I kinda of just portrayed it as if, but the python file has to be ran fully in order to define certain objects

Comment: what is `process` then? because you could replace the code inside the `proc` function with whatever you did to `drones[x]`

Comment: My `process` is like a defined class that takes in events, this class is then called and takes in `drones` and acts accordingly, I have other processes related under this class, so I need to define my class add the processes under the class and then launch.

Comment: `process` doesn't have to be a function/loop. If it is code, then you can put it into a function and call that function from `Pool.map()`